# Pogoplug software installation and a startup error with ubuntu 12.04 on a macbook

Tags: macbook

First I've got to say that I am very new to ubuntu and linux but I would love to learn more about it. So this is my first setup. I'm using an Apple macbook from 2008 with Ubuntu 12.04. (120Gb apple os snowlion, 80Gb ubuntu)

- When I start my system and I choose to start ubuntu the system boots quite fast. But after one minute or so I get a system error. Ubuntu asks me if I would like to send the diagnostic info to their debug center. How can I find out what is wrong? Is that do-able for a linux starter?
- In my house I also have a pogoplug device for filesharing. On the website of pogoplug I can find the program needed for installation. When I download the 32bit ***.tar.gz and try to open it with ubuntusoftwarecenter I get an error saying that Ubuntu Software Center can not open this file... How do I fix this. Is there a better way to install this third party software?

Answer (score 1):

1. You could try to review the report, though it probably won't make much sense to a regular user. Make sure, the system is fully updated, as updates provide bug fixes and stability improvements. The ultimate solution, if nothing else helps, is to disable the error reporting service. To do that, open a terminal window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>), and run :

   ```
   gksu gedit /etc/default/apport
   ```

   Change `enabled=1` to `enabled=0`, save and exit.
2. The `pogopluginstall.tar.gz` file you've downloaded is not intended for the Software Center. Rightclick it, and select `Extract here`. That will extract the actual setup file, `pogoplugfs`which is a command line utility for mounting the pogoplug file system. You can see what it does by running `./pogoplugfs --help`.

**Actual Setup**

First, create the `Pogoplug` folder in your home. We'll use it as a mount point in a moment.
Then open a terminal window, and run:

```
./pogoplugfs --user <your@emailaddress> --password <your password>` --mountpoint /home/pepper/Pogoplug
```

If all goes well, your pogoplug files should now be available through the Pogoplug folder.

Comment: yeah my friend . I just gave the general way .